# getJSON not satisfied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I have 3 selects:
country, region, city
When choosing a country to be updated select the region on the country.
here's the code. like written logically. but the region is not updated

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('select[name=ad_country]').change(function() {
            current_country = $(this).val();

            $.getJSON('./core/AJAX/advertisement_changecountry.php', {country: current_country}, 
                function(data) {
                    $('select[name=ad_region]').empty();

                    $.each(data.region, function(key, val) {
                        $('select[name=ad_region]').append('<option value="'+val.id_parent+'">'+val.name+'</option>');
                    });

                    $('select[name=ad_city]').empty();

                    $.each(data.city, function(key, val) {
                        $('select[name=ad_city]').append('<option value="'+val.id_parent+'">'+val.name+'</option>');
                    });
                });
            }
        );
}
```

Comment: Open the console and look for errors, and close the functions properly!

Comment: Use a modern browser and hit F12

Comment: forget `});` at the end..??

Comment: http://globauto.net/registration on step 2

Comment: you have `TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function` this error. please add validate plugin js.

Comment: Dipesh Parmar, no in full code it is

Comment: @user2231356 i am viewing you link http://globauto.net/registration and i see my mentioned comment error...check path is correct.

Comment: @user2231356 i can view source and can not find jQuery.validate plugin is included in page.

Comment: i dont understand. what is problem&

Comment: `$("#ani_register_form").validate({ ...})` => you have to add the validate plugin to your page like @DipeshParmar said. He doesn't know the validate method because the plugin isn't included...

Answer (score 0):

you have an error on your clossing tags

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the '}' at the end.Now try this Code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('select[name=ad_country]').change(function () {
            current_country = $(this).val();

            $.getJSON('./core/AJAX/advertisement_changecountry.php', { country: current_country },
            function (data) {
                $('select[name=ad_region]').empty();

                $.each(data.region, function (key, val) {
                    $('select[name=ad_region]').append('<option value="' + val.id_parent + '">' + val.name + '</option>');
                });

                $('select[name=ad_city]').empty();

                $.each(data.city, function (key, val) {
                    $('select[name=ad_city]').append('<option value="' + val.id_parent + '">' + val.name + '</option>');
                });
            });
        });
    });
```